# commenting form not entering in database

Tags: php, mysql

i am creating a ticketing system for my site and now it wont send to my database. now i can't find out where it goes wrong. so i hoped you guys could help me.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('connect.php');
session_start();
echo "Aan deze pagina word gewerkt, gebruik deze niet zolang wij hier mee bezig zijn";

//filled check
   if (isset($_POST["username"]) && isset($_POST["email"])&& isset($_POST["nummer"])&& isset($_POST["comment"])){
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $nummer= $_POST["nummer"];
    $comment= $_POST["comment"];

//prepered insert and finished message
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `comments` (username,email,nummer,comment) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $email, $nummer, $comment);
$stmt->execute();
    $msg = "De reparatie is aangevraagd. Er zal binnenkort contact met u worden op genomen.";
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<title>mytitle</title>

<div id="wrapper">

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<h1 id=logo>
    <a href=""> </a>
</h1>

<?php
    if(isset($msg) && !empty($msg)){
        echo $msg;
    }
?>

<div class="ticket-form">

<h1>Reparatie aanvraag</h1>
<form action="" method="POST">
<p><label> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbspUw naam : </label>
<input id="username" type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Uw naam hier" /></p>

<p><label> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp E-Mail : </label>
 <input id="email" type="text" name="email" required placeholder="naam@email.com" /></p>

 <p><label>Telefoonnummer : </label>
     <input id="nummer" type="text" name="password" required placeholder="uw telefoonnummer hier" /></p>

     <p><label>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbspOmschrijving van het probleem : </label>
        <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" required placeholder="Omschijving van het probleem"></textarea></p>

    <input class="btn tick" type="submit" name="submit" value="Verstuur reparatie aanvraag" />

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and then there is the contact.php mentioned. (this one is working as i use it for the other form for registration.)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "sqluser";
$password = "Welkom01!";
$dbname = "users";

$connection = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed". mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, $dbname);
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>
```

sorry for the messy code im still making it better and easier to read.

Comment: We need some more detail. Can you edit you question and include any error messages you are getting.

Comment: thats the problem it does not give any errors to me it just does not add anything

Comment: `$nummer= $_POST["nummer"];` and `name="password"` most probable pair you meant to match. You cannot rely on "id" alone `id="nummer"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code:

```
<p><label>Telefoonnummer : </label>
 <input id="nummer" type="text" name="password" required placeholder="uw telefoonnummer hier" /></p>
```

Change `name="password"` to `name="nummer"`

Comment: make sure you refresh the form before submitting. Can't see any more errors in the code. check if its going in if block.

Comment: im sorry i deleted the reaction because it works now i edited the wrong thing (test page that i have). i feel stupid now haha but thank you!